# I use OpenSMTPD on OpenBSD 5.8! How can I automatically encrypt E-mail with OpenSMTPD

Tags: email, encryption, openbsd, smtp

How can I automatically encrypt all outgoing E mail?

My scenario:
I use XXXX@gmail.com as my relay for all Emails my OpenSMTPD Server forwards All Emails to me as well as all Emails from somewhere to my OpenSMTPD Server. Nothing is stored on the Server. So I would like to encrypt all Emails before forwarding to my XXXX@gmail.com relay

Comment: I think to you need to such as email-rewriting in postfix and manipulating it. Or use `Sieve`. However I found Add-on in opensmtpd.

Comment: Please update your post and explain more....

Comment: I use XXXX@gmail.com  as my relay for all Emails my OpenSMTPD Server forwards all Emails to me as well as all Emails from somewhere to my OpenSMTPD Server. Nothing is stored on the Server. So i would like to encrypt all Emails before forwarding to my XXXX@gmail.com relay.

Comment: I update for you.

Comment: If you use a ready plugin , every one can decode your emais, I prefer to you write a plugin.

Comment: I have discovered today.       https://www.ciphermail.com/documents/quick-install-guide.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is an old question but the following might be helpful to others.

I just got to know that [zeyple](https://infertux.com/labs/zeyple/) does exactly what you are looking for. I never used it but I see that it has some credit. It's worth to try it.